# Can I do image reconstruction by combining two images using U-NET?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, steganography, unet-neural-network

I have been working with a Neural networks based image steganography project. The IEEE paper I am implementing is https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9293163 . In encoder module, I need to concatenate the message and the original image and reconstruct them using U-NET encoder. Now after this process, I need to get the steganographic image with hidden message as output.

Can anyone help me how can I do it?
Sorry if my explanation is not much technical. I am new to neural networks